# How can I solve the differential equation $ \frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}(y\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy}+x) = -A^2\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} $?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came across this differential equation while investigating how the concentration of a fluid varies with position $ x $ ($ A $ is a constant).

I tried to solve this by using a substitution, but I was unable to actually solve the equation for y. Wolfram Alpha did not come up with anything useful, either.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this? I would greatly appreciate if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: Yes. Does the $ \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy} $ term make the equation unsolvable? I may have obtained the term through algebraic blunder, however

Comment: The DE can also be written as $ (x \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} + y) \frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2} = -(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx})^2 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the equation is unchanged if you double $y$, and is also unchanged if you double $x$.
So substitute $y=\exp(w)$ and $x=\exp(t)$.  The result will involve $dw/dt$ and $d^2w/dt^2$ but not $w$ because the equation is unchanged if you add a constant to $w$.  It won't involve $t$ explicitly because the equation is unchanged if you add a constant to $t$.
The result is a first-order separable DE in $v(t)=dw/dt$

Comment: Is the solution of the form $ \arctanh x $ ? I am not really getting anywhere with this...

Answer (score -1):

Notice that $$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y}=\frac1{\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}}.$$ Hence, multiplying by $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ results in $$y''(x)[y(x)+xy'(x)]=-A^2[y'(x)]^2.$$ Let $y(x)=\exp[f(x)],$ hence $y'(x)=\exp[f(x)]f'(x)$ and $y''(x)=\exp[f(x)][f'(x)^2+f''(x)],$ thus $$\exp[f(x)][f'(x)^2+f''(x)](\exp[f(x)]+x\exp[f(x)]f'(x))=-A^2(\exp[f(x)]f'(x))^2$$ which simplifies to $$[f'(x)^2+f''(x)][1+xf'(x)]=-A^2f'(x)^2.$$ Let $g=f',$ so $[g(x)^2+g'(x)][1+xg(x)]=g(x)^2+xg(x)^3+g'(x)+xg(x)g'(x)=-A^2g(x)^2.$ This is a separable equation in $g(x).$